# question regarding recursive returns from java method

Tags: java, conditional-operator

Can anyone tell me what this statement means?  getHead is the first integer in an integer list:

```
        return (a.getHead() > m)? a.getHead():m;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as the following:

```
if((a.getHead() > m)) 
     return a.getHead();
else
     return m;
```

This is the idea behind it:

```
if ' evaluate condition' ? 'what to do if condition is true' : 'what to do if condition is false'
```

Answer (score 0):

`... ? ... : ...` is a ternary conditional.

The code you posted can be turned into

```java
if (a.getHead() > m) {
    return a.getHead();
} else {
    return m;
}
```

That code will return the whichever is larger: the head of the list or m.